# How to reach a Qt widget from another class

Tags: qt

I'm implementing a Tetris game. In Qt Designer I drew a Frame widget.
Then I organized a QtGlass inheriting from that Frame. So, in Qt Designer this looks like Object frame with QtGlass class. Now I would like to make the figure move within existing limits (walls etc). I'm trying to implement it like is shown below.

Well, I've come across the fact that I fail to reach my QtGlass object. So, I know that it has a method isMovementPossible(), but I don't know how to use it. My QtGlass instance seems to be called "frame", but if I use this name, I get the error "Unable to resolve identifire frame".

**QtGlass.h**

```
    #ifndef QTGLASS_H
    #define QTGLASS_H
    
    #include <QFrame>
    #include "Figure.h"
    
    class QtGlass : public QFrame {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    public:
        bool isMovementPossible();

    protected:
        Figure Falcon;
    ...
    }
```

**Figure.cpp**

```
#include "Figure.h"
#include "QtGlass.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

void Figure::set_coordinates(int direction) {
    previous_x = current_x;
    previous_y = current_y;
    switch (direction) {
        case 1:
        {//Qt::Key_Left:            
            current_x -= 1;
            if (frame->isMovementPossible()) {
                break;
            }
            current_x += 1;
            break;
        }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be accessible within your `Figure` method the `frame` variable would have to be either a global variable or a member of your `Figure` class (or of a superclass).

If you need access to your `QtGlass` instance within a `Figure` instance then you will need to pass a reference (or pointer) to it. You can either pass that to the `Figure` when it is constructed (assuming the frame outlives the figure) or pass it as a parameter to the method that needs it.

For example, if your frame always outlives the figures within it then you could simply do something like

```
class QtGlass; // forward declare to avoid circular header include

class Figure
{
public:
    Figure( const QtGlass& glass ) : frame( glass ) {}

    void set_coordinates(int direction) {
        // ...
        if (frame.isMovementPossible()) {
            break;
        }
        // ...
    }

    // other methods...

private:
    const QtGlass& frame;
    // other members...
};
```

and your `QtGlass` constructor could do

```
QtGlass::QtGlass( QWidget* parent )
    : QFrame( parent )
    , Falcon( *this )
{
}
```

Alternatively you could have a dedicated setter method for setting the frame on the figure if setting it at construction time is not convenient. The member would need to be a pointer in that case though (although the setter could still pass by reference).

Comment: Thank you very much. But at "Figure( const QtGlass& glass ) : frame( glass ) {}" I get frame wavely underlined and unable to resolve identifier frame error.

Comment: @Trts: You forgot to add the reference member.

Comment: I can't catch the idea. Could you clarify what I should do.

Comment: @Trts: I have added a little bit more to the example but there's really not much more I can say. It sounds like you are quite new to programming in general. Have you considered getting a good book on C++?